# javascript object to php using jquery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an array or a javascript object that I create like this:
`arr[arr.length]=obj`
where the obj is a classic JSON string like `{"id":1}`.

So `arr` seems to be an array of JavaScript Objects.

I can access to it like this:
`arr[1]`, `arr[2]`.
It could be even like `alert(arr[1].id);`

If i do:
    alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
I get the following:

```
[{"id":"2305","col":"1"},{"id":"2308","col":"1"},{"id":"2307","col":"1"},{"id":"2306","col":"1"}]
```

Whereas 
    alert(arr);
Gives me something like:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Now I need to pass it to a PHP script using jQuery's AJAX method. But it seems that it can get only combined strings like:

`{"id":"2305","col":"1"}` or `{"id":"2305","col":"1","id":"2305","col":"1"}`

But JSON.stringify parses the arr object successfully and my previous example of string I have seems to be a valid JSON string. How can I pass to PHP, should I really change the whole format of structure to be like the last sample?

UPD:
i forgot to mention that PHP's POST array is null if send '{},{},{}' string to it rather then '{}' string.

UPD:
I rewrote the code that was generated the string. Now i have a string like this:

```
{"2305":"1","2306":"1"}
```

It works if i pass it to PHP directly, like this:

```
   $.post({url: '../getItems2Cart.php', data:{"2305":"1","2306":"1"} ,
       success: function(response){alert(response);}
   });
```

If i send it like this, php return empty POST array:

```
$.post({url: '../getItems2Cart.php', data: JSON.stringify(str),.
       success: function(response){alert(response);}
});
```

To get clear, alert returns a proper JSON strong now:

```
alert('json str to php '+JSON.stringify(str));
//json str to php {"2305":"1","2306":"1"}
```

Ahh.. yes, and str is an javascript object, not string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can send the JSON and use `json_decode()` to turn it into a php array.

```
$.post('server/path', { jsonData: JSON.stringify(arr)}, function(response){
   /* do something with response if needed*/
});
```

in php:

```
$arr=json_decode( $_POST['jsonData'] );
/* return first ID as test*/
echo $arr[0]['id'];
/* or dump whole array as response to ajax:*/
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Sorry, i forget to mention that PHP's POST array is null if send {},{},{} string to it rather then {} string.

Comment: not clear what you are sending. If it matches the code after `I get the following:` in question should work fine. I don;t understand what `{},{},{} ` vs `{}` means. First should be an array `[{},{},{}]`

Comment: you aren't following my example and setting a key for the JSON string. POST needs key/value pairs... if you just send string you are only sending a value so $_POST will be empty

Comment: Probably i didn't get your example. If i sent the string directly - it works. If i stringify the object, it doesnt. There is probably a tiny detail, i've missed.

Comment: what do you mean didn't get it?? ... it's the code in my answer

Comment: So i did this already. It won't get at the serverside unlike if i pass a plain string to it. The examples in the second part of my first question. Thanks you.

Comment: you have ignored the way I created the data object... I gave you the `jsonData` key, and how to receive it in php

Comment: It gives me Notice: Undefined index: jsonData in /var/www/myelec/getItems2Cart.php on line 2

Comment: Anyway i was retrieving the whole POST array by print_r($_POST);

Comment: Wow, i've just repeated the code you gave me and it responsed me with a proper POST array )). Sorry for being inattentive. So, what's the secret, why it doesn't work as it should be according documentation?

Comment: I already explained the `key/value` problem you got into by generating your own code. What does google have to do with anything?