# Working with a Javascript object in PHP sent over ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, object

The following code sends (I hope so) a Javascript object to a php file through Jquery's ajax call.

```
var emails = {};
emails.name = email;
.
.
$('button.gmail').click(function() {                
$.ajax({ url: path,
         data: emails,
     type: 'post',
     success: function(status) { 
        alert(status); 
          }
   });
});
```

how can I examine this object in PHP and retrieve its keys/values?

Comment: This will encode the object into a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string, which will be available via `$_POST` in PHP.

Comment: Just do `print_r($_POST)` in your PHP file, and the alert will show whatever you received in the PHP file, which should be exactly the same as whatever you sent ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183837/javascript-object-to-php-using-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will encode the object into a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string, which will be available via [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) in PHP.

So if your data object is something like:

```
var data = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 10
};
```

Then in PHP you will have:

```
$_POST['foo'] //is "bar"
$_POST['baz'] //is 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $foo = $_POST['foo']; //this will assign whatever 'foo' was assigned in the javascript POST request
```