# Why am I unable to post a JS object to PHP successfully?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have researched many SO questions and followed the advice of those that answered, including [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183837/javascript-object-to-php-using-jquery-ajax), but I am still struggling to get this to work. I prepared a simplified test.

**JS & HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                data = {};
                data.subject = "Change the subject";
        /*
                $.post('php/test.php', { jsonData: JSON.stringify(data) }, function (response) {
                    console.log($(response).html());
                });
        */
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'php/test.php',
                    data: data,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    cache: false
                }).done(function (result, success, xhr) {
                    console.log("result=" + result);
                }).fail(function (xhr, desc, err) {
                    var msg = "Send mail - " + "\nError: " + "\n" + xhr.responseText;
                    console.log(msg);
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" name=  "form" >
            <input id="subject" name="subject" value="not a subject" />        
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

**EDIT**

I changed the $_POST to $_REQUEST - didn't help

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/*
$arr=json_decode($_POST['jsonData']);
echo $arr[0]['id'];
print_r($arr);
*/
    if (!isset($_POST["subject"]) || empty(trim($_POST["subject"])))
        throw new Exception('A subject is required.');       
    else $subject = filter_var(trim($_POST["subject"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    echo "subject=" . $subject;
```

**console.log**

> test.html:22 result=
>   ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'Exception' with message 'A subject is required.' in
> /home/deje/public_html/writers-tryst/php/test.php on line
> *12* ( ! ) Exception: A subject is required. in
> /home/deje/public_html/writers-tryst/php/test.php on line
> *12* Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0003248416{main}(  ).../test.php**:**0

**Addional error_log:**

> [10-May-2016 01:50:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
> 'Exception' with message 'A subject is required.' in
> /home/deje/public_html/writers-tryst/php/test.php:12 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}   thrown in /home/deje/public_html/writers-tryst/php/test.php on line 12

**EDIT**

Network table:

[image]

Comment: why did you comment out `/* $.post('php/test.php'... */`? Your (POST) arrays depend on it. Otherwise, it's defaulting to a GET. or specify it in your form `<form id="form" name=  "form" method="post">`

Comment: so tell us what error reporting threw back at you? You've an answer below btw, and if that's the issue, then you didn't include that error in your question.

Comment: I commented out the $.post because I tried it and it yielded the same results as did the answer provided after I added the method/type: POST. The error_log reports the same error information I posted (I am posting the error log as well). I did not abandon the question, I had some pressing business. It doesn't appear to me to be a duplicate of the question mentioned.

Comment: check the $_POST content by adding `print_r($_POST); die;` before your if statement. So you can see what you actually send to the php file.

Comment: Karlos, good idea. It reports 
result=Array
(
)

Comment: The answer below says use `method: 'post'` but I think that needs to be `type: 'post'`

Comment: . Thanks. You are right. It is "type" but in any case, that is not the issue.  Still searching for a solution to this strange problem.

Comment: @rontornambe I'll see if I can get a friend of mine to look at your question. He's much better at jQuery/JS than I am. But basically, the "post" isn't firing somehow.

Comment: FWIW, according to Jquery docs (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax): `Type` is an alias for `method`. You should use `type` if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Comment: Have you watched the request/response in browser's network tab?

Comment: Thanks, @iamvain2. I learned something. It is said that if .you do not laugh or learn something, the day has been wasted

Comment: I will try that in a few minutes. Thanks, @Jay.

Comment: @Jay -  posted the results of the network tab. I think the reference to test.php indicates it is posting. I chaged the $_POST to $_REQUEST

Comment: If you add `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to the top of your PHP script and submit, what do you get?

Comment: I changed the JS object I posted and used serialize instead. That worked. Thanks to all for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `method` for `$.ajax` is `GET`, change to `POST`

```
         $.ajax({
                    url: 'php/test.php',
                    data: data,
                    method: 'post',
                    cache: false
                }).done(function (result, success, xhr) {
                    console.log("result=" + result);
                }).fail(function (xhr, desc, err) {
                    var msg = "Send mail - " + "\nError: " + "\n" + xhr.responseText;
                    console.log(msg);
                });
```

Comment: By the way, the property is "type" not "method"e

Comment: According to Jquery docs (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): Type is an alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Comment: Turns out you were right after all. I did also change the data object to serialize as well.

Answer (score 0):

In test.php

```
$subject = array();
$subject[] = 'assign values';
echo json_encode($subject);
```